# How to FETCH using the value of a Refcursor variable

Tags: postgresql

I cannot work out how to FETCH using the value of a Refcursor variable on PostgreSQL.

Looking at [the reffunc2() example from here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN55130), which is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION reffunc2() RETURNS refcursor AS '
DECLARE
    ref refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN ref FOR SELECT col FROM test;
    RETURN ref;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
BEGIN;
SELECT reffunc2();
FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed cursor 1>";
COMMIT;
```

this works, but the final `FETCH` seems to require knowing in advance the name of the cursor, and then hardcoding it! But, from my own experimentation, this name varies and is typically something like `"<unnamed portal 5>"` (with the number varying).

I would like to be able to change the end of the example to something like:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
foo refcursor;
BEGIN
SELECT reffunc2() INTO foo;
FETCH ALL IN foo;
END $$;
```

so that I can select by name, responding to the actual cursor name which was passed back from `reffunc2`. But `FETCH ALL IN foo` gives

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 6: FETCH ALL IN foo;
                        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 85
```

and I cannot find any way to get this to work.

**EDIT:**

I've just tried this instead (following, as best I can, the suggestion to cast the result to `TEXT`):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
foo text;
BEGIN
SELECT CAST(reffunc2() AS text) INTO foo;
FETCH ALL IN foo;
END $$;
```

but now I get

```
ERROR:  variable "foo" must be of type cursor or refcursor
LINE 6: FETCH ALL IN foo;
                     ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: variable "foo" must be of type cursor or refcursor
SQL state: 42804
Character: 91
```

instead! (Obviously that's all very well, except that in my previous version the variable *was* a `refcursor`, and then it just gave a syntax error.)

Comment: This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56112658 where I am trying to do effectively the same thing in Npgsql. But I believe it is a separate question, since I have just tried, and realised I do not know how to (or even whether it is possible to) do this directly, even in hand coded SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To name the cursor, simply assign a string to the `refcursor` variable:

```
DECLARE
    ref refcursor := ''willi'';
```

Then the portal will have that name.

It is important that you assign the name *before* you open the cursor.

If you don't want to assign the name, simply cast the function result to `text`, that will give you the cursor name.

How to use `FETCH` depends on the environment where you call it:

- If you call it from SQL, you have to do it like this:

  ```
  FETCH ALL FROM willi;
  ```

  You'll have to construct the SQL statement using the result from the function, cast to `text`.
- If you call it from PL/pgSQL, you can use a variable in the `FETCH` statement, but you have to provide a destination for the result:

  ```
  DECLARE
     r refcursor;
     x text;  -- use the correct type
  BEGIN
     r := reffunc2();
     FETCH NEXT FROM r INTO x;
  END;
  ```

Comment: Thank you, but how should I apply this to fetch from the refcursor which is returned by something like `reffunc2()` above? (Where, I think, it has a name but I don't control the name.)

Comment: I have edited the answer to cover that. Cast the function result to `text`, that is the cursor name.

Comment: Thanks again, but it still it still doesn't yet work for me. See the bottom of my question where I've just updated it with another code sample to show what still isn't working for me. (Basically, yes, I can get the cursor name into a text variable - thank you! - but I still can't work out the syntax to *use* that text variable in the `FETCH`.)

Comment: Thank you for your continued assistance. That seems like the final answer for why I can't do this! Do you - by any chance - have any link to anywhere where that the fact that you can't do this is officially documented? And/or have any idea of the reason for not being able to do this? (Am I thinking about it the wrong way to think that it's something I'd want to do?)

Comment: It seems to me very natural that I'd want to put a refcursor variable (or at least a string variable) at the point in a FETCH statement where I want to fetch from a cursor with a name which I potentially cannot know until runtime (but which I can perfectly well know, at run time).

Comment: Combining your initial answer and helpful comments I have the full answer I was looking for! Is there any chance at all you could update the answer to point out that I can't actually do what I was trying to do in the first place, since that seems relevant! (For the reason you just said; and with the available workaround of using dynamic SQL which you suggested.)

Comment: PS If you have any more insight into this additional query, many thanks! How come Postgres explicitly complains that the variable *isn't* of type refcursor when it isn't (in the last added example in my question), but then the very same statement gives a syntax error when the variable *is* of type refcursor? That really does seem weird...

Comment: Further investigation showed that I have told you nonsense when I wrote that you cannot use a variable with `FETCH` in PL/pgSQL. See my improved answer.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, you can definitely `FETCH` from a `refcursor` variable inside a code block. But if I literally want to do `FETCH 100 FROM "c"` (actually, run as a `DbCommand.ExecuteQuery` in C#, as in my closely related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112658)) then I can still find no way to pass the cursor name to that small block of code in a parameter. Maybe I could knock up a tiny piece of code like what you've just suggested, and pass the cursor as a parameter to that? I'll try it!

Comment: Right. I wouldn't fetch from the cursor in PL/pgSQL, but in client code using the SQL command. Then you can `FETCH 100` and handle the result set in the regular fashion.

Comment: Fetch from the cursor in client code using which SQL command though, please? The only relevant command I know of is `FETCH n FROM "cname"`, which is the one I can't parameterize.

Comment: Right. But on the client that isn't a problem, because you can construct the `FETCH` statement from the result of the previous query in your client code.